# Loop through Cols & Rows with IF statement vba

Tags: vba, excel, for-loop

All,

I have written the below code to check if cells in the variable range have conditional formatting. However the code falls over at  "If Cells.ColorIndex = 3 Then" can anyone suggest why the error is occurring and if there is a better solution than the below code to achieve a loop through cols & rows (variable length)

```
Sub Check_Conditional()

Dim rng As Range
Dim row As Range
Dim cell As Range

Dim RW As Long
RW = ActiveSheet.Range("Total").Offset(rowOffset:=-1).row
Set rng = Range("O7:AB" & RW)

For Each row In rng.Rows
    For Each cell In row.Cells
        If Cells.ColorIndex = 3 Then
            MsgBox "Not all the cells have been filled out"
            Exit For
        End If
    Next cell
Next row

End Sub
```

Comment: Yes, you have a **Typo** , change `If Cells.ColorIndex = 3 Then` to `If cell.ColorIndex = 3 Then` , that's why you need to think of good variable names, not to make confusions like this.

Comment: unfortunately this still displays runtime error 438

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`cell.ColorIndex` is not a valid `Range` property.

If you mean to check the font's color then use `If cell.Font.ColorIndex = 3 Then`

If you mean to check the Fill color, then use `If cell.Interior.ColorIndex = 3 Then`

When you type in the editor, `Cell.` the VBA autocompletes it with the following options:

[image]

There's no `cell.ColorIndex` in the list:

[image]